# Is there a function to convert a string into a number and back for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have a lot of strings in a pandas dataframe, I want to assign every string a number for keras.

the string represent a location:

`CwmyNiVcURtyAf+o/6wbAg==`

I want to turn it into a number and back again. I'm using keras, tensorflow and pandas. Does one of the modules contain a function which does that? Or do I have to write a hashtable?

Like this:

`CwmyNiVcURtyAf+o/6wbAg==` => 1

`CwmyUSVcbBtiBQEkAN4bVbA=` =>  2

`CwmypSVdCRNYBv4MAFUTSRY=` =>  3

`CwnBoiVCjRNPBAAJ/ysTHw==` =>  4

`CwnBoiVCjRNfBv5QAEITCA==` =>  5

`CwmyUSVcbBtiBQEkAN4bVbA=` =>  2

I have ~8000 locations and each location is 15 times in the Dataframe

Comment: any reason you can't just use the table index? Or are there repeat strings?

Comment: sklearn got it. [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: there repeat and are not in order :/

Comment: @Pam he wants same label if repeted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider a one-hot encoding, which can be done easily with pandas via the `get_dummies` function. This will create binary columns for each "category" (i.e. unique string).

Comment: @Tim4497 LabelEncoder would do exactly what you're asking, BUT the risk is that if you are using these labels as features, the learner will interpret some numeric relationship between values (i.e. "CwmyUSVcbBtiBQEkAN4bVbA=" [encoded as 2] is 2x the value of "CwmyNiVcURtyAf+o/6wbAg==" [encoded as 1])

Comment: alrigth then I'm going to use the get_dummies function!

Comment: Excellent and good luck! Please mark this as the selected answer if you feel this closes this question.

Comment: Hey, I have a new question, when I' using the function, Python has to create a Array which has over 8000 columns and 15*8000 rows, now I have trouble with my memory, do you have an idea, how can I use all locations but still maintain a average RAM usage?

Comment: @Tim4497 this probably warrants a separate SO question. Preliminary, you could explore 1) grouping your categories in some meaningful way (I notice in your example the strings begin with 'Cwm', or 'Cwn', is this meaningful in some way? Could you collapse the 8000'ish values down into these two groups? 2) consider setting the `get_dummies` parameter `sparse` to True.

Answer (score 1):

This is `factorize`:

```
s = pd.Series(['CwmyNiVcURtyAf+o/6wbAg==', 'CwmyUSVcbBtiBQEkAN4bVbA=', 
               'CwmypSVdCRNYBv4MAFUTSRY=', 'CwnBoiVCjRNPBAAJ/ysTHw==', 
               'CwnBoiVCjRNfBv5QAEITCA==', 'CwmyUSVcbBtiBQEkAN4bVbA='])

labels, uniques = s.factorize()
```

Output:

```
# labels:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

And to convert back,

```
uniques[2]
# 'CwmypSVdCRNYBv4MAFUTSRY='
```

Comment: @quang-hong while this does answer OP's question, this kind of encoding can cause a learner to infer spurious connections if input as a feature. In that case, the implication is that there is an ordinal relationship between 0, 1, 2... n (the encoded values) when, in fact, these are categories which *do not* have that sort of meaning. See also: https://towardsdatascience.com/choosing-the-right-encoding-method-label-vs-onehot-encoder-a4434493149b

Comment: @xibalba1 I only answered the question as presented. As the solution does answer the question, I don't think it's fair to downvote. On the other note, what you said is **generally** true for deep learning model. It's not really true for, say, random forest. On the other hand, we don't really know if the order of these codes do or do not have some sort of meaning, as it **wasn't** mentioned in the post.